# Cannot find existing Nodes in vfx graph of Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I open up a newly created or an already existing vfx graph I sooner or later always end up with a grey blank space. One time I was lucky an found my nodes again but most often I cannot find them anymore in the infinite space of vfx graph. So is there a way to jump to the nodes or how a trick on how to find them? Also when I add context the nodes are not shown properly, like the lines seem to be collapsed and I have to dis- and enable the nodes if I want to see them properly. I'm also not able to fix that effectively. Just annoying...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a solution or a reason why the nodes are not shown properly but on how to find your nodes again.

You can press 'a' to focus on all nodes or 'f' to focus on selected nodes. That works also with Shader Graph.